# Include 3columns.phtml in my Custom module template folder

Tags: magento2

How do i replicate the the below template `3columns.phtml` in Magento2 in my Custom module.

I believe there is no `3columns.phtml` in Magento2?
How to configure the same?

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::page/3columns.phtml</argument>
        </action>
     </reference>
```

I also need to know what exactly is the look or behavior of `2columns-left` or `1-column` as we specify in layout xml file.
When and what situation we use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do inside your xml file,
There are 3columns template available in magento 2.

You have get it inside **`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/3columns.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body></body>
</page>
```

Comment: if done so, no need of the whole <reference> tag?..How to include as shown for my custom module?

Comment: you have to just keep your code inside body tag in above syntax.

Comment: I have not made any change to my code inside <body>, except added layout="3columns" in the <page>?

Comment: just remove var folder and check